# upload file to s3 from local using AWS CLI without hard-coded credentials(access id and secret access key)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

My requirement to upload file from local to s3 using aws cli  but don't want to use access ID and secret access key while running in command line.

Any suggestions!

Comment: Can also use IAM role, instead of the IAM user credentials.

Comment: Why don't you want to use access keys?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you **never** put AWS credentials in program code.

**If the code is running on an Amazon EC2 instance**, assign an **IAM Role** to the instance. The code will automatically detect and use these credentials.

**If the code is running on your own computer**, run the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command and enter your IAM credentials (Access Key + Secret Key). They will be stored in the `~/.aws/credentials` file and will be automatically accessed by your code.